# Exterior product of one-forms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $\mathcal M$ be a compact $3D$ differentiable manifold and let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be three one-forms on $\mathcal M$. I want to consider the scalar quantity
$$
F(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)=\int_\mathcal M (\alpha\wedge \beta\wedge \gamma),
$$
and I would like to know if it is possible to relate $F$ to some invariants of the manifold. Most typically, in the non-compact case (and provided that the integral makes sense), I take three vector fields $X,Y,Z$ on $\mathbb R^3$ and I want to check the quantity
$$
f(X,Y,Z)=\int_{\mathbb R^3} \det\bigl(X(x),Y(x),Z(x)\bigr) dx.
$$
A similar question: may I relate $f$ to some geometric properties of the vector fields $X,Y,Z$?